# Do the Eigenvectors find by use PCA on a set of data point, a good replacement for Random Projection when I later on use L1Magic to reconstruct the sparse vector? 

Tags: compressed-sensing, linear-algebra, pr.probability, random-matrices

Concretely if I use the first k eigenvectors find by PCA with a point set A,to project another  sparse vector b to k dimension subspace, then use L1-magic to recover b. Will this be better than a Random Projecton. L1-magic is a software tool for compress sensing. b is not a vector from A, but possibly have the same distribution of A.

Comment: Can you flesh this question out a bit? For example, where does b come from (is it an element of A)? What is L1magic--some kind of compressed sensing software? etc.

Comment: @Steve Hi Steve I changed my question a little, hope than will help.